# Unity. Find script that creates GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know where the script is that creates the GameObjects after I rightclick and create a GameObject in Unity scene?
[image]

Basically I want to know if it is possible to create an object with script but while in editing, almost like making a custom editor.

I want to code the objects size, position mesh and all components I need on it rather that adding it manually in the scene panel

Comment: [`GameObject.CreatePrimitive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CreatePrimitive.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a submenu of GameObject. So you can create an editor script just like other menus.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuExample
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/3D Object/My Custom Cube")]
    static void Create()
    {
        var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    }
}
```